# Where oh where did my ETH go?

Tags: coinbase, gdax

Sent a small amount of ETH from GDAX to a hex at Bittrex exchange. Coinbase receipt on Etherscan says "success," and the hex is right but no ETH arrived at Bittrex exchange. What gives? It's been 2.5 days.

Comment: You have to ask Coinbase/Bitterx they are private companies.  Open a support ticket with them.